# Xkbmap overwriting Xmodmap

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

I use Xmodmap to remap some of my keys. I want to use Xkbmap to have a keyboard shortcut to switch keyboard layouts. When I run `setxkbmap us`, my keyboard layout changes but my Xmodmap changes get lost. I have to reload the file with `xmodmap .Xmodmap`.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Hermes 4.8.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 31 18:51:30 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`pacman -Q | grep xmodmap`:

```
xorg-xmodmap 1.0.9-1
```

`pacman -Q | grep xkbmap`:

```
xorg-setxkbmap 1.3.1-1
```

Answer (score 1):

`xmodmap` and `setxkbmap` are conflicting utilities. Calling `xmodmap` will reset changes made by `setxkbmap` and vice versa. You have to pick one of them to do your keyboard configuration with. And also figure out if your system is using one or the other.

You may encounter issues if for example you use `xmodmap` in your `.xsession` or similar and after the session file is parsed your DE calls setxkbmap through some script.

Comment: setxkbmap usually overrides everything, while xmodmap mdoifies the existing keymap (overriding only what is specified). so it can be useful to first run setxkbmap and then xmodmap, e.g. if one is more comfortable with xmodmap syntax as opposed to the almost undocumented xkb syntax.